# Как убрать вертикальный разделитель в макете?

Tags: 1с

Ситуация такова - закончил макет, сам по себе он большой, и в конце обратил внимание на выделенный красным разделитель.
Я поробовал всевозможные пункты из меню "Таблица" но этот разделитель(или что оно есть не удаляется). Я удалял как разделители, так и области печати.

Чтобы это могло быть, как считаете?

[image]

1с8.2

Comment: Откройте свойства всей колонки и снимите галочку КонецСтраницы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решился - это вертикальня граница для строки, не учавствующей в отчете. после ее удаления эта граница исчезла.